# PostgreSQL bad plan: the frequency of a tag depends on the project!

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I try to simplify a problem that I've been investigating for weeks.

Suppose that you have a large table like this:

```
SUBSCRIBERS
----------------------------
id | project_id | tags | ...
----------------------------
1  | 1          | ['en', 'something']
2  | 1          | ['en']
3  | 1          | ['de']
4  | 2          | []
5  | 2          [ []
...
```

Now suppose that *project 1* has millions of rows and most of them have the tag `en`.

Also *project 2* has millions of rows, but there isn't any row with the tag `en`.

The following query generates terrible execution plans:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE project_id = 2 AND tags @> ARRAY['en']::varchar[];
```

Indeed the planner sees the following:

- project = 2 is very common
- tag = 'en' is very common

Thus the planner thinks that there are many rows to return! However no rows match the actual condition.

That creates crazy choices in the indexes or even seq scans! I mean, I verified that it takes 20 minutes instead of a few ms, due to the wrong choices!

I have already tried the following (without any benefit):

- SET STATISTICS 10000 for project_id and tags
- CREATE STATISTICS on project_id, tags
- SET random_page_cost = 1
- make sure that the perfect indexes (compound, btree, gin, etc.) exist on project_id and tags
- frequent ANALYZE and much more...

I think that the problem is that **PostgreSQL should collect separate stats on tags for each project id**. However it seems that there is no way to achieve that...  Any idea?

Also I think that **CREATE STATISTICS doesn't work properly on array columns** (maybe works on the whole column instead of the single values). Any specific information about this?

Comment: Rather than using arrays, use a normalized relational database model. Then your queries might be simpler and work better.

Comment: For yourself, your customers, your family life, your karma - use a [`JOINING TABLE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)!

Comment: Agree with the two comments above. Postgres is awesome for letting you store things in lots of different ways, but sometimes you've just got to go back to basics...

Comment: @Vérace It's a SaaS and the tags are set dynamically / on the fly / freely by customers... so I don't see how you could use a joining table here.

Comment: Of course you can - you let the customer update the joining table -  by definition, you're letting them update parts of the database - these tags, inststead of that,  point them to the table!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be just a planning problem.  If you could force the planner to pick the exact plan you want, what plan would that be?  I can't think of one.  If you have one in mind, please describe it. ("Knowing that there are no rows to return so immediately returning nothing" is not an actual plan in this case, unless you have constraints in place to enforce it)

Comment: @jjanes The correct choice is to use the composite indexes... Instead the planner is convinced that there are many rows to return (wrong) and uses seq scan or smaller indexes. If I could let the planner know about the **correlation between project_id and the array values**, then it could make **the right estimate** and choose the proper index (ms vs minutes).

Comment: Help us out here.  Which composite index?  There is no magic solution here (other than possibly normalizing and then using `CREATE STATISTICS` on the join table) just a series of workarounds.

Comment: @jjanes Otherwise, I could point the execution in the right direction, based on a previous count at application level... however **PG doesn't support index hint :(**

Comment: @jjanes This was a general question. I have created a new question specific for my exact query here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260817/postgresql-filtering-on-array-and-ordering-produces-wrong-plan-bad-index-choi

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there is no way to do this, and that CREATE STATISTICS only looks at arrays in their entirety, not their individual components.

Perhaps CREATE STATISTICS can be expanded in the future to do that, but someone would have to volunteer to implement it, and I am not aware of anyone working on such a thing.

Note that even if "tag" were a scalar, CREATE STATISTICS wouldn't help you in versions 10 or 11, as the mcv type of statistics were not added until v12, and that is what you need. So presumably what you would need is a new type of statistics, call it arrray_mcv.