# PostgreSQL: filtering on array and ordering produces wrong plan / bad index choice

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

This is the story if a nightmare... I have this table:

```
                                        Table "subscriptions"
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('subscriptions_id_seq'::regclass)
 project_id | integer                     |           |          | 
 endpoint   | character varying           |           |          | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 uid        | character varying           |           |          | 
 tags       | character varying[]         |           |          | '{}'::character varying[]
 trashed_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 ...

Indexes:
    "subscriptions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_subscriptions_on_endpoint" btree (endpoint)
    "index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_created_at" btree (project_id, created_at DESC)
    "index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_tags" gin (project_id, tags) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL
    "index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_tags_using_btree" btree (project_id, tags) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL
    "index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_trashed_at" btree (project_id, trashed_at DESC)
    "index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_uid" btree (project_id, uid) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL
```

I have this query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) 
SELECT "subscriptions".* 
FROM "subscriptions" 
WHERE "subscriptions"."project_id" = 12345 
  AND "subscriptions"."trashed_at" IS NULL 
  AND ((tags @> ARRAY['crt:2020_02']::varchar[])) 
ORDER BY "subscriptions"."created_at" DESC 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;
```

**Note**: It's a SaaS that produces the query on the db based on user inputs (sent through a REST API), so I don't have full control on the tags used for filtering (which can also include AND, OR and NOT conditions). So please don't focus on this exact tag filter: just consider that there are some conditions on `tags` (variable). Also note that tags are not pre-defined: they are attached to the rows *on the fly* by the customer and I don't have control on tags (they can be any string).

This is the result:

```
          QUERY PLAN                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.56..13577.18 rows=30 width=382) (actual time=1195740.956..1195740.956 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5918464 read=3226736 dirtied=1537
   ->  Index Scan using index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_created_at on subscriptions  (cost=0.56..5556910.68 rows=12279 width=382) (actual time=1195740.951..1195740.951 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (project_id = 12345)
         Filter: ((trashed_at IS NULL) AND (tags @> '{crt:2020_02}'::character varying[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 9202438
         Buffers: shared hit=5918464 read=3226736 dirtied=1537
 Planning Time: 4.319 ms
 Execution Time: 1195741.912 ms
(9 rows)
```

As you can see this simple query takes several minutes!

I have tried the following:

### Forcing use of a different index

I simply change the ORDER BY to this:

```
ORDER BY ("subscriptions"."created_at" + interval '0 days') DESC
```

And the time goes **from several minutes to a few ms**:

```
                                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=63775.08..63775.16 rows=30 width=391) (actual time=566.728..566.728 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5375 read=2492
   ->  Sort  (cost=63775.08..63856.39 rows=32522 width=391) (actual time=566.727..566.727 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: ((created_at + '00:00:00'::interval)) DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=5375 read=2492
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on subscriptions  (cost=1200.28..62814.56 rows=32522 width=391) (actual time=566.709..566.709 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((project_id = 12345) AND (tags @> '{crt:2020_02}'::character varying[]) AND (trashed_at IS NULL))
               Buffers: shared hit=5372 read=2492
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_tags  (cost=0.00..1192.15 rows=32522 width=0) (actual time=566.706..566.706 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((project_id = 12345) AND (tags @> '{crt:2020_02}'::character varying[]))
                     Buffers: shared hit=5372 read=2492
 Planning Time: 2.511 ms
 Execution Time: 566.827 ms
(14 rows)
```

The problem is that it is a hack and produces terrible results and even seq scan when thousands of rows match the condition.

However it shows that PG could choose a better plan!

## Improving stats

In order to have better plans you try this:

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptions ALTER project_id SET STATISTICS 10000;
ALTER TABLE subscriptions ALTER tags SET STATISTICS 10000;

CREATE STATISTICS stats_on_subscriptions ON project_id, tags FROM subscriptions;

VACUUM ANALYZE subscriptions;
```

Nothing changes.

## Creating the perfect indexes

I have tried (only *one at a time*) the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_subscriotion_fields_1 ON subscriptions (created_at DESC, project_id, tags) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_subscriotion_fields_2 ON subscriptions (project_id, created_at DESC, tags) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_subscriotion_fields_3 ON subscriptions (project_id, tags, created_at DESC) WHERE trashed_at IS NULL;
```

However they are completely ignored by PG: the planner keeps using `index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_created_at`. I have really no idea why: I think that `idx_subscriotion_fields_1` would be a perfect choice for most queries (whether they return a few rows or many).

I have even tried to temporary disable `index_subscriptions_on_project_id_and_created_at`: instead of using the other indexes PG chooses a seq scan!

## Improving other settings

I have tried to make frequent autovacuum and setting `random_page_cost = 1`. Nothing changes.

## Control the plan from application level

I have also tried to search whether I can use *index hints*, but unfortunately PG doesn't allow them :( It's frustrating. Otherwise, from my application, I could use a count (which is fast for the same queries) and point PG in the right direction.

## Final thoughts

Filtering some rows on tags and taking the most recent items doesn't seems a complex need.

However on this large table PG has many issues and I can't find a solution. I start thinking that PG has several missing features (good statistics on array values, index hint, ordered btree indexes on array values, support for multitenancy, etc.) and is not suited for big data. I hope that I am wrong since we have built the entire SaaS on PG. Every post keeps saying the same things that I have already tried: any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure how well PostgreSQL can estimate `@>` searches on `jsonb` columns. The non-normalized data model sure doesn't help, so if something is not suited for big data, I'd point at the model. No other database I have heard of has better indexing features for JSON data. If you can estimate beforehand what would be the best choice, why don't you modify the `ORDER BY` clause depending on the outcome? The hack is just as hacky as a query hint.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the comment. You are not the first to tell that non-normalized data doesn't help... however that structure in my case makes many operation easier and updates fast. It makes sense. Also the **index structure should be decoupled** from the data structure (e.g. you can even define indexes over functions). I don't understand why PG released array support if statistics doesn't work properly and indexing is hard (and doesn't even allow hints because it is sure that it makes the best choices).

Comment: There is a wide margin between "works properly" and "magically guesses everything correctly", which is what you would like. If you think that query performance and indexing are independent ("decoupled") from your data model, that is wishful thinking. You **have** a "hint": the `ORDER BY` clause you are using. There is no kind of "conditional query hint" in any database I am aware of.

Comment: "*whether I can use index hints, but unfortunately PG doesn't allow them*" - but then Postgres is flexible enough to be able to support extensions that can do that: https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan (I personally essentially never used hints in Oracle because more often than not they break after minor patch upgrades, so I never missed them in Postgres)

Comment: What if you wrap it into a CTE? https://pastebin.com/cTFH6sn3 as the inner query is planned independently from the outer query in Postgres 11 (or in 12 with the `materialized` option). This might result in a stable plan even without the "order by trick"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it takes a few ms, thank you. The downside is that, like the order trick, it cannot be used when a tag matches many rows... so I can use it *only* as a hint when there are *a few rows*.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't want magic: actually I am asking to have more control on the execution. Here's what I mean: **Is there any workaround to make PG always use `idx_subscriotion_fields_1` (without removing order from main query)? That would be the perfect index for filtering and ordering, fast both for queries that match a few rows and for queries that match many rows: what do you think?** The problem is that, without hints, I cannot make PG use that index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe BTW many experiments, [like this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105545/66756), show that using GIN is better than a JOIN, so I am convinced that the problem is not my schema.

Comment: @collimarco: You provided a lot of helpful information, but forgot some basics: Postgres version? Cardinality of `subscriptions`? Tables size (`pg_relation_size('subscriptions')` and `pg_table_size('subscriptions')`. Any table or index bloat? Available RAM & CPU and according server configuration. How many distinct `project_id`? How many `trashed_at IS NULL`? How many distinct tags (elements of array `tags`)? Avg cardinality in `tags`? Avg cardinality in filter ARRAY? Tags evenly distributed? Is it always `LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter PG v11; 50M subscriptions; vacuum every few hours  / avg. 50k dead rows; 16 vCPU, 32GB RAM; 10k project ids; <1% trashed at; cannot make any assumptions on tags, it varies a lot depending on project (usually a few tags per row, less than 10); a tag can appear only once or on millions of rows... they are not evenly distributed (e.g. a project can use a tag on millions of rows and another project not use it at all, since tags are set by the customer - not pre-defined); yes, there is always limit / offset for pagination (offset varies).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe "No other database I have heard of has better indexing features for JSON data." ... I disagree with that: for example MongoDB has **[multikey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)** which would be helpful in my case. PG doesn't support that. Also note that my `tags` column is not a `jsonb` column, it's simply an `array` column.

Comment: What about adding an index on `(project_id, created_at DESC, tags) WHERE (trashed_at IS NULL)`? Looks better for this query than any of the indexes you have.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: `tags` is an array, no good like this in a btree index. The core problem of the query is the same as in your classic https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684 . Array instead of range. (Plus, `OFFSET` is a bad idea in addition.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter right, I didn't realize it was similar issue! And a hard one, indeed.